# error: no match for 'operator>>'

Tags: c++

I'm reading C++ Primer 5th Edition when i came to this part. It's a code it provided that I have to use but I keep getting

> error: no match for `'operator>>'` (operand types are `std::istream` {aka `std::basic_istream<char>}` and `Sales_item`)

on line `std::cin >> book;`

I tried looking it up and rewriting the code but I can't get it to work so I need help to fix this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sales_item.h"


int main()
{
    Sales_item book;
    // read ISBN, number of copes sold, and sales price
    std::cin >> book;
     // write ISBN, number of copies sold, total revenue, and average price
    std::cout << book << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `operator>>(std::istream &in, Sales_item &book)` for `Sales_item` class?

Comment: Is there an `operator>>` defined for `Sales_item`? It won't work without custom code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the operator is undefined is because operators work for specific types. Your type that you created, `Sales_item`, does not have that operator - unless you overloaded it to work for your specific type. See [this question on Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for more info.

Comment: This would be a good answer if you added code on how to do it, like here: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/

Comment: @staticx I'll get on that.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner that would be appreciated

Comment: @user3821846 Could you post your Sales_item class? I'd be happy to tailor the code sample for your specific need rather than wasting time making some example.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner thanks anyway but I managed to fix the problem

Comment: @user3821846 Great, hopefully my answer helped!

Comment: @user3821846: If you have solved your problem, it would help to create your own answer or delete this question.